# data fetched from database but id of this this table item not showing

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi i have update my question to explain you my problem easily.Okay so, 
**What i wnant and whats wrong with me?**
i code a product form where i require getcatlist.php which help me get value from sql database and show in product page, **Snapshot of product form** [product form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyjr1.png)

**Product form code**

```
    <section class="main-section">
    <article class="prod-item">
        <h3>Product Form</h3>
        <form action="addproducts.php" method="get" name="product_form">    
            <section class="select-box">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <?php   require_once("getcatlist.php"); ?>  
                <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['cat_id']; ?>" >
            </section>

        </form> 
    </article>
</section>
```

**my javascript in product form page used to create query string code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showCategory(str)
    {   
        document.product_form.action="addproducts.php?cat_id="+str;             
    }       
</script>
```

**getcallist.php page code which fetch data from databse and show in select tag **

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);   

require_once("../data_connect.php");
$error_msg = "";
$cat_id = "";
$catsql = "SELECT Cat_id,CategoryName FROM category order by Cat_id asc; ";
$cat_query = mysqli_query($connect,$catsql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($cat_query);
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
    if($numrows == 0)
    {
        $error_msg= "No Categories Found";
    }
    else{
                echo "<select name=\"category\" id=\"category\" onchange=\"showCategory(this.value)\" >"; 
                echo "<option value=\"null\">Select your category</option>";
        while($catrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query))
            {
                if ($catrow['Cat_id'] == $cat_id){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$catrow['Cat_id']."\" selected=\"selected\">".$catrow['CategoryName']."</option>";
                }
                else{
                                echo "<option value=\"".$catrow['Cat_id']."\">".$catrow['CategoryName']."</option>";
                }
            } 
                echo "</select>";
    }
 ?>
```

**here is my ajax code which move to another page when i click on dropdown list**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**/$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#category").change(function(){
                var code = $(this).val();

                if(code == 1)
                {
                    $('.main-section').load('addconsoles.php');

                }
                else if(code == 2)
                {
                    $('.main-section').load('addaccessories.php');
                }
                else if(code == 3)
                {
                    $('.main-section').load('addgames.php');
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

okay i wants to create a query string of category list, when i click on any category option in dropdown list it wont show me any thing in url. This is the big problem i face and also when i try to set and get value in php oop class(require in product form page) it won't set and get when echo it.
Please help me out from this problem, Thanks

Comment: `when I try to get its id from form`... `when I insert data into database the category id is null` I see no code to do either of these actions in your question. If you have a problem with this functionality, it would make sense to show the relevant code. Can I assume you have already verified that the final HTML output by getcatlist.php is valid HTML, containing the correct IDs in the dropdown options? If you haven't checked it, then please do so first. Then if there's still a problem, show us the final HTML, and also your code which receives the postback of the form

Comment: getcatlist.php shows drop down list and items correctly and its id also their is no problem in getcatlist.php the problem I'm having is in the form it won't able to make query string when selecting category from drop down list

Comment: selecting a value in a dropdown does not, on its own, cause the form to submit, if that's what you mean? Or do you mean there is no server variable called "category" populated when the form is submitted? As I mentioned, it's not clear. We cannot even see your form, or the code which runs when the form is submitted. Please answer my questions above and provide the requested extra code, I did ask for a good reason - it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: Let me explain you.

Comment: I'm all ears...

Comment: i have update my question to explain you in a better way please read my question again and help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have somewhat mis-understood how HTML forms work.

The code you've got will not work as you expect because you have got the `cat_id` field defined *twice* within your form - once in the hidden field you created, and again when you alter the action method of the form via the JavaScript. However when your JavaScript runs, it modifies the "action" string, but the hidden field will not change, and when you submit the form, the browser will submit the value from the hidden field, and ignores the value you manually added to the "action" method. This is just the default behaviour in such a situation, in order to resolve the ambiguity you created.

Therefore if at the time the page was first loaded, there was no value in `cat_id` (which seems likely, looking at your code), then no value for `cat_id` will be sent to the server when the form is submitted.

However, all of the code I described above is actually unnecessary. You can directly use the value of the dropdownlist as the `cat_id`. Simply changing the "name" parameter of your `<select>`, as follows:

```
echo '<select name="cat_id" id="category">';
```

will make the `cat_id` parameter change to whatever is in the selected value of the dropdown when the form is submitted.

You do not need the "showCategory" function, or the hidden field.

So the form can be

```
<form action="addproducts.php" method="get" name="product_form">    
  <section class="select-box">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <?php   require_once("getcatlist.php"); ?>  
  </section>
</form>
```

without the hidden field, and the "showCategory" JavaScript function can be deleted entirely.

N.B. From this code it seems you have no way to submit this "addproducts" form to the server. It's not clear whether you have some other JavaScript elsewhere which controls this and is triggered based on some other event, and/or whether you need to add a "submit" button to the form. Either way, nothing will be sent to the server until you cause the form to be submitted, or provide a way for the user to cause it.

I hope this is useful, please comment if you still find anything unclear.